# Are there any programming pitfalls of using a map with an empty interface as the KEY

Tags: go, hashmap, go-interface, go-map

Are there any programming pitfalls of using maps in this manner:

```
type Set struct {
    theMap map[interface{}]struct{}
}

StringSet := NewSet("abc", "pqr")
IntSet := NewSet(1, 2)
DateSet := NewSet(time.Date(2021, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC))
```

Just to be clear, I know what I'm doing is probably against the spirit of several 'best practices', but that isn't my question here. I'm specifically thinking of **programming** issues like memory issues due to different element sizes, increased chance of hash collisions, performance degradation due to increased type assertion, etc.

Some more info:
I need to create some 'sets' of various datatypes in my application. I see in Essential Go that the best way to use sets is to [use a map with an empty struct as the value](https://essential-go.programming-books.io/use-map-as-a-set-90b9baa6982e4dc1a8ea21976757cae5).

However, in the absence of generics, I would either need to make a new type of Set for each type of data/element which I wish to store in my sets:

```
type StringSet struct {
    stringMap map[string]struct{}
}
type DateSet struct {
    dateMap map[time.Time]struct{}
}
type IntSet struct {
    intMap map[int]struct{}
}
```

...or, use the empty interface as the key of a hashmap:

```
type Set struct {
    theMap map[interface{}]struct{}
}
```

The 2nd option works very well (you can find my complete code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/oGWUBk2mLx9)), but I'm worried that I'm overlooking  something obvious and will run into problems later.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: *"issues like memory issues due to different element sizes, increased chance of hash collisions, performance degradation due to increased type assertion, etc."* -- No, none of that. In fact, `map[interface{}]T` is used multiple times in the standard library.

Comment: Děkuju @mkopriva